# How to use complete database from MySQL without using models in Django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, database, django-admin

I am new to Django, and I was given a complete MySQL database with all relations and tables set. I am trying to put this data from MySQL database into my admin site.

I want to know if there is any other way to retrieve data from MySQL database without using Django models.

**MySQL Database**
[MySQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlmVQ.png)

I tried to use autogenerated model, but it did not work for me. Data doesn't show up in the admin site. (P.S. I do not necessarily require data to be in admin site, I am just trying to use it any ways possible)

**Auto-generated model by django**

[python manage.py inspectdb > models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLoY.png)

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Ligand

admin.site.register(Ligand)
```

Please, let me know if you know any ways to use data from MySQL database that was not created using Django model.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

python manage.py inspectdb can be run to detect and generate models. More on it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: I couldn't find the way to post this into admin site or either use the data using database API.

Comment: For using the admin tools, you will need to register the models created in your admin.py file